# Is it suitable to use 200 HTTP status code for a forbidden web page?

Tags: http

What is the difference when we use `200` response status code for a forbidden page with an error message saying 'Access Denied' instead of using `403` response status code?

Are there any security implications?

Comment: If there is some kind of issue with displaying the page to the user - why do you want to send a status code that says everything went fine?

Comment: This is not Java. 2** codes are for "OK", so **no**, it is not suitable for that.

Comment: That really depends where you draw the line between http as a transport protocol and your business logic. If you have a login form that displays a fancy error using a lot of after a failed login attempt, I would go with 200 since that html was printed correctly and your business logic was executed without any errors.

Comment: anyone who gives you a definite answer with such little info is doing you a disservice. it really depends. if you try to view someone's facebook feed without being logged in for example you are taken to a login page, not given a 403...

Comment: Why should you use a 200 status if you have correctly printed HTML?! You can use correctly printed HTML for 400 as well.

Comment: This is for one of the webapps embedded in my project which is not exposed to user as a separated/independent application. when this application is hit using the port configured for it, the page shown currently gives an error message with 200 response code instead of 403. I assume 403 is intended for forbidden service but not really sure what is the implication of using 200 instead of 403

Answer (score 3):

The HTTP Response codes convey information about how **the server** has processed your request. So, if the server responds with 200, it means: "*OK, I have received your request and processed it successfully*". If it returns 403, it would mean: "*I received your request successfully, but you don't have access to this resource*".

However, technically they are both returned in the same format, in the same way in the response HTTP header like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

The difference is in the meaning. And the meanings are defined in the [standard](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html).

So, when you are responding with code `200`, you are telling the client that it is all good and dandy. If you are responding to client with `403`, you are saying that the client doesn't have permission to this resource. Remember, there can be different clients: web browsers, crawlers, ajax requests from javascript, etc.

So, if you are sending a login form with `200` code:

1. Users who are using a **web browser** would understand that they need to login.
2. Google **crawler** will index your `members/quality-content` URL with the login form and will not understand that actually, the original content is different and it should not index this page with the login form.
3. Javascript with **ajax callback** will run `success` callback, when it should be running `error` callback function.

So, basically, make us all a favour and follow the standards! :)

Answering your second question, no it does not make your application any less secure.

Comment: Great! You may want to select this answer to move your question into the closed state.

Answer (score 1):

Response status codes are intended to help the client to understand the result of the request. Whenever possible, *you should use the proper status codes*.

The semantics of the status codes are defined in the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231), the current reference for HTTP/1.1.

While the [`200`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1) status code indicates that the request has succeeded, the [`403`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3) status code indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it:

> [**6.3.1.  200 OK**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1)
>
> The `200` (OK) status code indicates that the request has succeeded. The payload sent in a 200 response depends on the request method. [...]

> [**6.5.3.  403 Forbidden**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3)
>
> The `403` (Forbidden) status code indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.  A server that wishes to make public why the request has been forbidden can describe that reason in the response payload (if any). [...]

Returning [`200`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1) will work, for sure. But why would you return [`200`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1) if you can return a much more meaningful status code? If is there any good reason, this should be added to your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: @sahilarora If this answer solves your question, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this decision might be that error message was not visiable using Internet explorer like described here: [How do I suppress "friendly error messages" in Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544048/how-do-i-suppress-friendly-error-messages-in-internet-explorer)
Actually the correct way is to use the right HTTP error code and make the error message longer than 512 bytes as described here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/294807